# Setting up SwiftData with iCloud share - difference to Core Data

Tags: core-data, cloudkit, swift-data

How to set up the sharing mechanism with SwiftData (Sharing between users)?

Are there any differences to the tutorials that can be found on this topic for iCloud + Core Data?

When looking at the initializer for Modelconfiguration what does **sharedAppContainerIdentifier** mean or how is it set up?

```
let modelconfiguration = ModelConfiguration(
    schema: Schema([Item.self]),
    inMemory:false,
    readOnly:false,
    sharedAppContainerIdentifier:nil,   // <------- here
    cloudKitContainerIdentifier: "..."
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First to your last question, as it seems to be the step documented first in apples docs:

You need to set up an app group: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/adopting_swiftdata_for_a_core_data_app#configure_the_sample_code_rpoject

and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-app-groups

This is needed, if you want to share the same data across multiple of your apps.

I suggest you follow the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Envpr8UAgYk

Comment: Thanks. perhaps I didnt understand `sharedAppContainerIdentifier` right. Because I thought it would have something to do with: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/shared_records/sharing_cloudkit_data_with_other_icloud_users. My question was meant to the sharing between iCloud users

Comment: sharedAppContainer refers to the groupContainer for sharing your db with other apps on the same device. As far as I know, there's no SwiftData APIs yet to share with other iCloud users. I don't know if you can instantiate a CKDatabase manually with the same ck identifier and do share that way? I'm still looking into that.

Comment: @hayesk I am struggling with the same thing, but it seems there is no native way to start sharing directly with SwiftData. Did you find anything useful? Thank you.

Comment: I have not. Looks like the best answer is to not use the SwiftDate cloud container, but use Apple's new CKSyncEngine to sync. It's a fairly big job to do, and will be challenging detecting.